# Split an asset into two assets in Hyperledger Composer.

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, blockchain, hyperledger-composer

Is it possible to split an asset into two or more assets in Hyperledger Composer?

For an instance consider a usecase of using blockchain for food supply chain where food items are considered as assets (batch wise). In the supplychain, at a distribution node, each food item batch (asset) is distributed to several other nodes which means the asset is divided into many smaller assets.

In Hyperledger composer, is there a way to address this kind of scenarios? If not how can we achieve the requirement?

Comment: Yes, you can split assets, but your use case suggests they are different classes once they reach distribution nodes. They would likely be modeled separately -  but you can have a relationship from the 'DistAsset' (at distribution nodes) back to the OriginatingAsset (batch/origin) . Each asset class has differing values, you can always have transactions (activity) linking one back to the other as appropriate. Also it seems 'OriginatingAsset' would have a different set of attributes/state to that of a 'DistAsset' (representing its state, destination distribution node etc etc)

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony Thank you. I think the approach you suggest is suitable and how can I split an asset or merge two assets in Hyperledger Composer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you could create to different assets:

- the batch
- the food item, which is the part of food distributed.

The food item contains the reference to the batchID.
In the transaction processor you could implement a logic in which the batch quantity is decremented each time the food is distributed.

```
asset Batch identified by batchId {
  o String batchId
  o Integer batchQuantity
  // other fields
}

asset FoodItem identified by foodId{
 o String foodId
 --> Batch batchId
 o Integer quantity
 //Other fields
}
```

Comment: Thank you. It makes sense. But in your solution is it possible to trace back to the origin of main asset (eg : the farm where the main asset/batch is originated). If it is possible, how to do so?

Comment: If you add a field to the Batch which represents the creator, you can retrieve that information. Or also you can retrieve the creator of the batch by search who submited the initial transaction in the historian registry